# Whitespace validation error message

Tags: validation, user-interface

This may not be very technical, but in my application I want to prompt the user when the form input element value has whitepsaces only.

My english grammar is not the best so I hope some of the better english speaking folks can help me with this sentence:

```
alert("This field can not contain whitespaces only: " + labelName);
```

Thanks in advance
R.

Comment: "whitespaces" is jargon. and you're lucky if `labelName` is meaningful. A red asterisk will do, in my opinion.

Comment: A red asterisk means required to me. Eg. the value is blank (str.length === 0). But users can insert spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "This field cannot be left blank" ? I'm not sure that many people outside programming understand 'whitespace' as programmers do.

Comment: I think I go for this one. 
Thanks!